# "Failed to execute script pyi_rth_qt4plugins" error while running exe

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt4, pyinstaller

I have made my application using PyQt4 and it's executable using pyinstaller. The executable runs fine on my system. My system also has PyQt5 installed.

The problem is that when I try to run the same executable on the target system(client's system), it gives me an error `Failed to execute script pyi_rth_qt4plugins`. The client system doesn't have Python or any version of PyQt.

I wanna know why is this happening. I'm not even able to locate where is the `pyi_rth_qt4plugins` located in the executable. Do I need to install Python and PyQt in my client's system as well?

Comment: Can you post your code please, so that i can give you a working solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53702850/10849457 Check here too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the answer from the long thread here https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2461

In site-packages (where PyInstaller is located) edit the following file:

```
PyInstaller/loader/rthooks.dat
```

Remove this line:

```
'PyQt4': ['pyi_rth_qt4plugins.py'],
```

This error also occurs in Python3.5 if you are using 3.5 you can downgrade to 3.4 to avoid the error
check here https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2207

or if you don't want to downgrade python you can upgrade to PyQt5

Comment: I've developed the application using Python 3.7.6.....and the exe was made about 2 months ago. Can you tell me a way to make it work by probably modifying the .exe?

Comment: There is no possible way to make it work by modyfying exe. the only way is in the code or while generating exe

Comment: Upgrading to PyQt5 looks like the best option to me.